# ViewBag Message not displaying in view in mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

"New Movie" is not displaying in View. Instead, it is displaying "ViewBag.Message" directly. But the data in ViewModel works fine.

NewMovie Action Method:

```
public ViewResult NewMovie()
{
  var movieType = _context.MovieTypes.ToList();
  var viewModel = new MovieViewModel { MovieTypes = movieType };
  ViewBag.Message = "New Movie";
  return View("MovieForm", viewModel);
}
```

MovieForm View:

```
@model VideoRentalApp.ViewModel.MovieViewModel
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Movie Information";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>ViewBag.Message</h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>`. The asterisk `@` denotes a variable reference. Otherwise the razor compiler interprets the string as just that, a string.